# Kth smallest element in a array

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, stl

I was writing this code for finding Kth smallest element in array where l= starting index and r = ending index is given to us as input parameter in function.

```
class Solution{
    public:
    int kthSmallest(int arr[], int l, int r, int k) {
        //code here
        arr.sort(l,l+r+1);
        int count =1,i=1,var =0;
        while(count<=k)
        {
            var = arr[i];
            count++;
            i++;
        }
        return var;
    }
};
```

I tried to use sort function in my code but this code is giving error in my sort function ,given below which is not understood by me.

prog.cpp: In member function int Solution::kthSmallest(int*, int, int, int):

prog.cpp:18:13: error: request for member sort in arr, which is of non-class type int*

```
     arr.sort(l,l+r+1);
         ^
```

Comment: [std::nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element).

Comment: Note that `arr[]` is a C-style array. The C++ equivalent would be `std::array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr` is type `int *`, so a primitive type and a primitive type don't have any member function. So `arr` don't have any `sort()` member function, so it cause an error.

If you want to sort `arr`, use `std::sort` from `<algorithm>`.

```
std::sort(arr + l, arr + r + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use the [std::nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) algorithm, it will give you the element at the position in the array if the array where sorted.
To use it you need iterator so you will have to convert your C array `arr[]` into a `std::array` if you don't want heap allocation or a `std::vector` if you want to be more flexible.

> Note: if you use C++ 20 you can use [std::ranges::nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/nth_element)

Answer (score 1):

In C++, arrays like `arr` are not objects, so they have no members like `sort` that you can access using the dot operator.

Instead, try using `std::sort` from the `<algorithm>` header:

```c++
#include <algorithm>

std::sort(arr + l, arr + r + 1);
```

This example assumes that:

- `l` is the leftmost index you're sorting.
- `r` is the rightmost index.
- both `l` and `r` are valid indices for `arr`.